# Can we have multiple rollback while using Transaction with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
DB::beginTransaction();
if(some condition)
{
    if(some condition)
    {
    DB::commit();
    }
    else
    {
//first rollback
    DB::rollback();
    }
}else
{
//second rollback
DB::rollback();
}
```

can we have multiple rollback statement in an transaction?

Comment: In general, I would try to avoid nesting transactions.

Comment: I would recommend throwing `Exception`s and doing the `rollback()` in the `catch`- and the `commit()` at the end of the `try`-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code, only one rollback will be executed, depending on the conditions. You can write multiple `DB::rollback()`, as long as only one gets executed.

To answer to the question, is possible to have multiple rollbacks, if you use nested transactions, and you use the rollback/commit to go back to the previous level.

Comment: so @Cristik as you said only only one rollback can be call be at one time

Comment: If you want your application to behave deterministic you need to make sure every `BEGIN` call is balanced with either a `COMMIT` or a `ROLLBACK` one. I think MySQL doesn't complain if you send it multiple rollback calls, however that's something you should avoid.